# Oracle DB Recovery

Tags: oracle, recovery, rman, disaster-recovery

Before I start, I just want to mention that I am not a DBA, I am a programmer/developer who also happens to look after the database. So if I say something wrong, my apologies in advance.

We recently experienced a massive city wide power surge which killed our database server. We have multiple databases running on the server (RHEL6 - Oracle 11gr2). I back up all the data using rman and the command "backup database plus archivelog delete input" and then take an impdp dump of one particular schema so that we can import it into our test environments over night. After our server was destroyed, the only thing we could recover from the hard drives was the backupset folder which contains a lot of bkp files. And that's about it. I don't have a control file or the DBID of the database. I do however have a data dump that's 3 days old

Is there any way we can recover the database on to a new host?

Regards

Alex

Comment: Do you also have files in the servers $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/ directory named snapcf_${ORACLE_SID}.f  and spfile${ORACLE_SID}.ora or init${ORACLE_SID}.ora ?

Comment: There are lot of people who become de facto DBAs because there is no one else to do the job.  Some of them are in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
there is.
transfer the files to a new server, if you have one, using the same file structures.
next create a init.ora file with the dbname and control_file parameters.
Start the instance using that init.ora in nomount.

If you happen to have snapshot controlfiles in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/ of you database,
start rman:

```
rman target=/
restore controlfile from '/where/is/it/o1_mf_ncsnf_TAG20130803T022352_8zrqqfc4_.bkp';
alter database mount;
restore database;
recover database;
alter database open;
```

Without controlfile it's a little trickier but still possible. A nice explanation is here [How to restore an rman backup without any existing control files](http://blog.ronnyegner-consulting.de/2010/11/03/how-to-restore-an-rman-backup-without-any-existing-control-files/)

Tip: always end your backup by creating a copy of your current controlfile:

```
BACKUP AS COPY CURRENT CONTROLFILE FORMAT '/tmp/controlfile_%Y%M%D.ctl';
```

Preferably on a smarter location than /tmp. Not only does it contain your database layout, also the administration of your most recent and most valuable backup.

Comment: WE pretty much lost everything on that server. The only reason we have the backupset is because I copied them from the server 5 hours before the power surge hit us.

Comment: do you have the logs of the last backup? If so, check where the controlfile did go and issue restore controlfile from '/where/it/went/bkp_XXXX';

Comment: Nope. Just the bkp files. This is pretty much all we have:     http://pastebin.com/dhc804Gy

Comment: Try restoring controlfile from the smallest file. It may be autobackup of controlfile.

Comment: Well tried that. I ended up with an error message : backup is set to archivelog cannot be processed.

Comment: Ok ... after a lot of messing about I managed to get the server to recover the Control File. However doing a recover database fails because it cannot file the bkf files and it doesn't seem to like the control file. Any more advice? By the way I never said thank you for all your kind advice. M apologies ... thank you very much for all your help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Alex, first make sure that the bkf files are on the same location as where they were on the old server. Same path. Use rman list backup of datafile 1 to see the path where it is expected to be.

Comment: I have mate : this is the output I get for list backup http://pastebin.com/6w87wUQy

Comment: Do the file exist in this location? </u01/app/oracle/flash_recovery_area/SIPR/backupset/2013_07_30> ? If not, make sure that they are moved to that location and run a crosscheck backup all; After that: restore etc.

Comment: After messing about even more - I managed to restore all the files. However it won't let me recover the database. I end up with a ORA-19804 (cannot reclaim XXX bytes disk space from XXX limit). I have modified the db_recovery_file_dest_size to 200G and I still get the same error. I am almost there!

Comment: Right! So I got further ... Just cannot get the database to open (I am able to mount correctly)  http://pastebin.com/UD3BhyX1

Comment: was it a cold backup? (media recovery complete) In that case, just issue alter database open; BTW: strange error messages you got .... :-( Check :select * from v$datafile;

Comment: Alter database open doesn't work. I get the same error message.

Comment: Finally managed to get it all working! Thank you very much mate.

Answer (score 0):

I think o1_mf_ncsnf_TAG20130803T022352_8zrqqfc4_.bkp contains your control file. [Format Of Backup Pieces Managed In FRA (Doc ID 566680.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=566680.1), says that "c" in third section indicates a control file.

Comment: I tried recovering the controlfile from that file but it didn't quite work. I ended up with an error message : backup is set to archivelog cannot be processed. ik_zelf originally suggested the idea.

Answer (score 0):

After restoring the controlfile from o1_mf_ncsnf_TAG20130803T022352_8zrqqfc4_.bkp (in your comments on ik_zelf's post you said that you'd managed to restore it) you've tried to perform a restore which imply a crosscheck and, since the backup files were in a different location, RMAN marked them as `EXPIRED`.
You have 2 choices.

- A) Check the paths with `RMAN> list backup` , recreate the paths, move the backup files to their old places and then in RMAN `crosscheck backup all` *(lot of work here if there are several different folders)*
- B) Run `RMAN> catalog start with '/new/backup/path'` and just `restore` /  `recover`

Comment: Cheers mate. I did manage to restore the database files but I am stuck as recovering the database itself. I end up with a ORA-19804. I have modified the db_recovery_file_dest_size to 200G and I still get the same error. Thank you for your advice though mate. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Check if path in `select name, value from db_recovery_file_dest` exist and if there is enough space.

PS* Maybe is a good situation to point out that its a good idea for your company to hire a DBA

Comment: I've typed it wrong. It's: `select name, value from v$parameter where name='db_recovery_file_dest'`

Comment: The idea is I eventually attend training and get certified. But in the short term I have to sort things out. I have checked the parameter already and it's correct. I got past that error. The issue was because of a shared drive where the recovery data was being held.